# fetch data from api in Accordion list react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to fetch the title from

> https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json
>   in accordion view in react native 
>   how can i do this

here is my code but is display static data using array 
now i want to display data from api

```
const dataArray = [
  {
    title: "First Element",
    content:""

  },
  {
    title: "Second Element",
    content:
      "content1"
  },
  {
    title: "Third Element",
    content:
      "content2"
  }
];

class LocationScreen extends Component {



componentDidMount(){
    return fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json ')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {

        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: responseJson.data,
        }, function(){

        });
          })
      .catch((error) =>{
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
                 <Content padder>
          <Accordion
            dataArray={dataArray}

          />
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
```

Comment: change your dataArray to this.state.dataSource

Answer (score 0):

Replace {dataArray} by {this.state.dataSource}

```
render() {
    return (
      <Container>
          <Content padder>
              <Accordion
                  dataArray={this.state.dataSource}
              />
          </Content>
       </Container>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggest @slashsharp, use this.state.dataSource.

In the render method, you're using '{dataArray}' which is your static data.
If you want to start to display these static values, use this:

```
const dataArray = [
{
    title: "First Element",
    content:""

},
{
    title: "Second Element",
    content:
        "content1"
},
{
    title: "Third Element",
    content:
        "content2"
}
];

class LocationScreen extends Component {
state = {
    dataSource: dataArray, //init state with your static data
}


componentDidMount(){
    return fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json ')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {

        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: responseJson.data,
        }, function(){

        });
          })
      .catch((error) =>{
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
          <Content padder>
          <Accordion
            dataArray={this.state.dataSource} // changed to this.state.dataSource

          />
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the

`this.setState({
   dataSource:responseJson.movies
}`

and use `dataArray={this.state.dataSource}`

Answer (score 0):

```js
renderContent(section, _, isActive) {
    return (
      <Animatable.View
        duration={400}
        style={[
          style.wrapServiceDesc,
          isActive ? style.seriveActiveDesc : style.seriveInactiveDesc
        ]}
        transition="backgroundColor"
      >
        <Animatable.Text
          animation={isActive ? "bounceIn" : undefined}
          style={[style.serviceDesc]}
        >
          {section.text} // fetch from API
        </Animatable.Text>
      </Animatable.View>
    );
  }

componentDidMount() {
    const url = "url";
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        this.setState({
          dataSource: responseJson.data
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

render() {
    return (
      <Container>
          <Content padder>
          <Accordion                
                activeSections={activeSections}
                sections={this.state.dataSource}
                touchableComponent={TouchableOpacity}
                expandMultiple={multipleSelect}
                renderHeader={this.renderHeader}
                renderContent={this.renderContent}
                duration={400}
                onChange={this.setSections}
              />
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
```

```
renderContent(section, _, isActive) {
    return (
      <Animatable.View
        duration={400}
        style={[
          style.wrapServiceDesc,
          isActive ? style.seriveActiveDesc : style.seriveInactiveDesc
        ]}
        transition="backgroundColor"
      >
        <Animatable.Text
          animation={isActive ? "bounceIn" : undefined}
          style={[style.serviceDesc]}
        >
          {section.text} // fetch from API
        </Animatable.Text>
      </Animatable.View>
    );
  }

componentDidMount() {
    const url = "url";
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        this.setState({
          dataSource: responseJson.data
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

render() {
    return (
      <Container>
          <Content padder>
          <Accordion                
                activeSections={activeSections}
                sections={this.state.dataSource}
                touchableComponent={TouchableOpacity}
                expandMultiple={multipleSelect}
                renderHeader={this.renderHeader}
                renderContent={this.renderContent}
                duration={400}
                onChange={this.setSections}
              />
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer a bit? That will help OP or future readers better.